# Perspective transform in THREE JS

Tags: three.js, textures, perspective

I found few incomplete threads regarding Perspective Transform using Three JS.

I was looking to have a rectangle with video texture on it, and each corner one after another will animate to fullscreen or in reverse. As each corner animates the texture should stretch. Something like this [demo](http://www.html5.jp/test/perspective_canvas/demo1_en.html) but in Three JS.

It will be great help if someone can point to an example, docs or resources to get this effect.

Comment: @DacreDenny `new THREE.PlaneGeometry(16, 9)` consists of 2 triangles, so when you try to move vertices (corners) you'll get incorrect distotions in the triangles. The solution could be using a plane of 2 width segments and 2 height segments (8 triangles) with bilinear interpolation.

Comment: @prisoner849 After spending some good amount of time on basics it made sense. I am able to achieve the effect with ease. Thanks.